# Bootstrap in HTML Web Part

Tags: 2010, jquery, html, boot-strap

I got HTML/CSS from our Designer to implement on a Sharepoint 2010 page. This page is using bootstrap.

I implemented it with HTML Web Part and also tried to split the web page layout and work directly on aspx site. But it is not working correctly in IE.

Also tried to show the page via iframe and on Chrome it is working correctly, but not with IE.

Any advices to use bootstrap on a Sharepoint 2010 subsite (at best only in a Web Part)?

Comment: I believe you need should add the bootstap js files into the head section of the page?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Worked on an own reset for bootstrap 3 and SharePoint 2013. It is not complete and not tested for things like publishing sites. But it is a good and clean starting point for your own projects:
[github link](https://github.com/FlorianLeitgeb/sp-2013-bootstrap-3-fix)

Comment: thats not true :) you have to reset some css from bootstrap to fit in sharepoint... this is an reset for older bootstrap version: https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/e50b95bbe1ff20ea9b8a... you habe to modify it a bit to fit for your needs... the main problem is the border-box and the img with width 100% for all img tags.. if you fixed that, it should work like a charm :)

Comment: You are right. After some time now, I am also working on a css reset for bootstrap 3 with SharePoint 2013. I edited my answer according to this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, to use this "version" of bootstrap:

http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010/theme/thebootstraptheme

This is a customized bootstrap solution extra for sharepoints wich you can use.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not free.

Comment: sure, it is! Use the "bootstrap-theme" http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010/theme/thebootstraptheme

Comment: no, its NOT FREE , all the templates are starting with $999 !!!

Comment: okay - it WAS free :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a version that I forked off an [existing](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/e50b95bbe1ff20ea9b8a) gist. 
The css works well for our Vuejs apps that are delivered via the Content Editor WebPart in our on-prem 2013 environment. 
I really just wanted to isolate the bits of of bootstrap's css that impacted the classic look at feel.
I don't have access to 2010, so your mileage might vary.

[Baseline CSS overrides for SharePoint](https://gist.github.com/danawesome/91cba156a096e8a60f85e2e521da6061)